# error while migrating asp.net application to azure app service and database

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, database-migration

I configured one asp.net application in my local machine . Then I migrated that web app frontend to azure app service and backend to azure database. Then I browse the web app using url provided in the azure app service, at that time I got an error like this

[image]

this is the error I got when the assessment part is completed, before migration

[image]

Comment: It is impossible to tell. Maybe some missing configuration? Either change the web.config as described or take a look at the logs (preferred)

Comment: Please provide the logs containing the actual error information or temporarily change the configuration to display the detailed developer error page. The current screenshot does not provide any information that can be used to analyze the error.

Comment: Your error indicates that you are using the local / on- premise connection string. Make sure you are using the Azure DB Connection string

Comment: Getting same error, it's working fine from PROD browser but not outside from it.

Comment: <customErrors mode="Off"/> Please add this tag under webconfig's <system.web> tag, let us know the actual error it returning.